# Salesforce Data as Entry Event Source

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, marketing-cloud-connect, entry-criteria

When using Salesforce Data as Entry Event Source, is it possible to make the segmentation directly from the Salesforce Contact object, with specific criteria, so that any Contact that corresponds to the criteria can be injected in the Journey Builder?  (I mean without necessarily having these Contacts as new created records or as updated Contacts in Salesforce)

Thank you

Regards

Ludivine

Comment: are you need to use segmentation in journey builder ?

Comment: Actually i want to make a segmentation on salesforce data as target for my Journey. I search for the easiest way without having to make a SQL query on synchronized data extensions, etc... but when I look at the feature on the Journey Builder and Salesforce data Entry Source, it seems that we can only inject newly created Contacts OR Updated Contacts that correspond to the criteria, but that we can not use it as a segmentation tool directly on the whole base of Contacts ? But I may be wrong...! could you please confirm me that ? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well - the entire idea of Salesforce Data Entry Event is to inject a contact into a journey based on data changing in Sales Cloud. You set up the criteria on the contact object itself, or on any object relating to Contact. This can e.g. be Case which triggers injection of the contact into journey once Case status is set to *closed*.

You can define the criteria to be evaluated when a record is created or updated (or both). And this evaluation will be done in near-real time:
[image]

There is no need to use the data from Synchronised Data Extensions, as long as you ensure your Entry Event Data is sufficient to support the journey. You select what objects and fields should be used for the [Journey Data](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_jb_journey_contact_data.htm&type=5) once you configure the entry event. Keep in mind this data is a snapshot from the time the contact enters the journey. If you want to monitor changes in the contact record throughout the journey, you will indeed need to reference your synchronised data extensions in the contact model and use it in e.g. decision split.

Comment: Thank you very much @Lukas Lunow So i guess that I can't use it directly as a segmentation tool to select the contacts I want to enter the journey if they are not newly CREATED contacts or UPDATED contact in Salesforce.